# How to draw a trapezium?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java and have a question about drawing a trapezium.
At the moment I'm not sure where to start.
Do you have any idea, where I could start, and what to take care of?
I don't want to get finished code from, just some inspiration, because at the moment I really have no idea

```
/*
 * Trapezium.java -
 */

/**
 * Represents a isosceles trapezium, that can be 'drawn' to the standard 
 * output stream. A trapezium is drawn with a foreground and background colour. 
 * The fore- and background colours are represented by two (different) characters. 
 * Each trapezium consists of a number of individual lines. Each line contains an 
 * odd number of foreground characters to be able to retain symmetry.
 */

public class Trapezium {

// Attributes/ Fields

    /**
     * The character representation of the default background.
     */

    private static final char DEFAULT_BACKGROUND = 32;


    /**
     * The character representation of the default foreground.
     */
    private static final char DEFAULT_FOREGROUND = 42;


    /**
     * The character representation of the indentation.
     */
    private static final char INDENTATION = 32;


    /**
     * The number of lines used to draw the triangle itself.
     */
    private int height;    

    /**
     * The maximal number of characters per line used to draw the 
     * trapezium itself.
     */
    private int width; 

    /**
     * The size of the margin in characters.
     */
    private int margin;


    /**
     * The foreground character.
     */
    private char foreground;

    /**
     * The background character.
     */
    private char background;

    /**
     * The number of characters at the top line of 
     * the trapezium.
     */
    private int topWidth;

    /**
     * The number of characters at the bottom line of the trapezium.
     */
    private int bottomWidth;


// Constructor

    /**
     * Creates a trapezium accepting a top and bottom width, 
     * a fore- and a background character as well as a value 
     * for the margin.
     * 
     * @param topWidth - the width at the top of the trapezium as a non-negative number.
     * @param bottomWidth - the width at the bottom of the trapezium as a non-negative number.
     * @param foreground - the character used to draw the trapezium's foreground
     * @param background - the character used to draw the trapezium's background
     * @param margin - the non-negative number of characters to be used as margin at the left 
     * and right of the trapezium
     * 
     */
    public Trapezium(int topWidth, int bottomWidth, 
                char foreground, char background,
                int margin) {
        this.topWidth = topWidth;
        this.bottomWidth = bottomWidth;
        this.foreground = foreground;
        this.background = background;
        this.margin = margin;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a trapezium with the given width at the top and bottom 
     * and the size of the margin. 
     * Default values are used for the foreground and background.
     * 
     * @param topWidth - the width at the top of the trapezium as a non-negative odd number.
     * @param bottomWidth - the width at the bottom of the trapezium as a non-negative odd number.
     * @param margin - the non-negative number of characters to be used as margin at the left 
     * and right of the trapezium
     * 
     */
    public Trapezium(int topWidth,
            int bottomWidth,
            int margin) {
        this.topWidth = topWidth;
        this.bottomWidth = bottomWidth;
        this.margin = margin;

    }

    /**
     * Creates a trapezium without a margin with the given width at the top and bottom. 
     * Default values are used for the foreground and background.
     * 
     * @param topWidth - the width at the top of the trapezium as a non-negative odd number.
     * @param bottomWidth - the width at the bottom of the trapezium as a non-negative odd number.
     */

    public Trapezium(int topWidth,
            int bottomWidth) {
        this.topWidth = topWidth;
        this.bottomWidth = bottomWidth;
    }

// Methods

    /** 
     * Draws the triangle with no indentation. 
     * This method calls the more general 'draw' method.
     */

    public void draw() { 

    // while
    }

    /**
     * Draws the triangle with the given indentation.
     * 
     * @param indentation - the indentation at which the triangle is drawn
     * 
     */
    public void draw(int indentation) {
        ;
        //while
    }

    /**
     * Rotates the triangle 180 degrees.
     * 
     */
    public void rotate() {
        ; 

    }

    /**
     * Prints a 'run' of a given character.
     * 
     * @param character - the character to be repeated.
     * @param length - the number of characters to print.
     * 
     */
    private void printCharacterRun(char character, int length) {
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a newline to the output.
     * 
     */

    private void printNewLine() {
    }

}
```

The Tester is in another class

```
trapezium = new Trapezium(5, 11, '*', '-', 2); // create a new Trapezium
trapezium.draw();
trapezium.rotate();
trapezium.draw(15);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to [ask] and [the open letter to students](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You’ve basically copied your assignment, said you have no idea where to start. This seems like a good opportunity to meet your professor or hire a tutor. It looks like you should start by taking a stab at the draw method. Write out on paper how you would draw a triangle and then try some code.

Comment: Thank you. I read the open letter to students now, and what I really didn´t want was anybody writing code for me. I know, that I won´t learn anything with finished code :)
but THANK you for the tipp to talk to my tutor, I think I should try this first
I just don´t know where to start. 
with all the other programs I didn´t had this trouble. :)
maybe after that i come back with a more precise question :)